# Needhelp with Snowflake pivot

Tags: pivot, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to pivot some data in Snowflake, but in all honesty, I dont really understand it.  So the data is like this:

```
Create table Company_rank (company_name varchar(100), Public_rank varchar(20), Peer_rank varchar(20), Online_rank varchar(20), Company_id integer)

Insert into Company_rank (company_name , Public_rank , Peer_rank , Online_rank , Company_id )
VALUES ('ABCCompany', '20','35', '15',1)
VALUES ('BCDCompany', '25','32', '20',2)
VALUES ('DEFCompany', '18','20', '25',3)
```

What I need to see is the ranking as rows, which I can use to join to another table, for each company.  I need the company_id to stay as a column, as I need that for joining, but I dont think that's possible? So, basically, I need the type of ranking and the company_name to be available for joining, as another table has ranking_name, and company_id

Sorry if this seems jumbled!

As above, sorry this is my first post,.

I was thinking of this:

[expected results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MajW.jpg)

But then I've lost the ability to get a key from another table, which needs both the rank_type, and the company_id (this can be derived from company_name or company_id)

So ideally the end result, I would have three tables, which would look like this (company_rank is my staged data, which I am trying to get into these):

[final results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOtDd.png)

Comment: Please update your question to show the result you want to achieve based on the source data you've provided

Comment: Please update your question, rather than add comments, so that all the information is in one place

Comment: Can you glue your questions and what is expected result ..It is easy to know what you are trying to acheieve.

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add all relevant information directly to your question preferably as editable text

Comment: Im really sorry, Im no good at html, and the text all just bunches up :-(

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about formatting - though using tables is pretty straightforward https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is just an UNPIVOT.

```
Create table Company_rank (company_name varchar(100), Public_rank varchar(20), Peer_rank varchar(20), Online_rank varchar(20), Company_id integer);
    
Insert into Company_rank (company_name , Public_rank , Peer_rank , Online_rank , Company_id )
        VALUES ('ABCCompany', '20','35', '15',1)
              ,('BCDCompany', '25','32', '20',2)
              ,('DEFCompany', '18','20', '25',3);

-- unpivot the above table
select 
      company_id
    , company_name
    , rank_type
    , rank_value
from company_rank
    unpivot(
        rank_value for rank_type in (
              Public_rank
            , Online_rank
            , Peer_rank
            )
        );
```

Output:

| COMPANY_ID | COMPANY_NAME | RANK_TYPE | RANK_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABCCompany | PUBLIC_RANK | 20 |
| 1 | ABCCompany | ONLINE_RANK | 15 |
| 1 | ABCCompany | PEER_RANK | 35 |
| 2 | BCDCompany | PUBLIC_RANK | 25 |
| 2 | BCDCompany | ONLINE_RANK | 20 |
| 2 | BCDCompany | PEER_RANK | 32 |
| 3 | DEFCompany | PUBLIC_RANK | 18 |
| 3 | DEFCompany | ONLINE_RANK | 25 |
| 3 | DEFCompany | PEER_RANK | 20 |

Your example output image has each company as a column.
I would advise achieving that transposition in a downstream reporting tool as -- I assume -- the companies are dynamic so the number of columns would not be deterministic (as well as other issues). Additionally, it would be impossible to join the company id as each column is a company.

This format will allow you to join the company, as well as filter on the company and type of rank.